# salto de linea string popover en JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

No puedo hacer un salto de línea en `JavaScript`, el `\n` y la etiqueta `<br />` no me funcionan. Que otra forma hay para realizar salto de linea de linea específicamente en el `eventRender`.

Gracias.

Este es mi código.

```
let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                this.calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                    plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
                    locale: esLocale,
                    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                    timeZone: 'UTC',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth'
                    },
                    events: this.events,
                    eventRender: function (info) {
                        $(info.el).popover({
                            title: info.event.title,
                            placement:'top',
                            trigger : 'hover',
                            content: info.event.extendedProps.content+'<br />'+info.event.extendedProps.description,
                            container:'body'
                        }).popover('show');
                    }
                });
                this.calendar.render();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas hacer un salto de linea puedes hacerlo a través del código html con el tag **< /br >** pero debes activar la opción html con `html: true`:

Ejemplo:

```
$(info.el).popover({
                            title: info.event.title,
                            placement:'top',
                            trigger : 'hover',
                            html: true, /* activamos el uso de codigo html */
                            content: info.event.extendedProps.content+'<br />'+info.event.extendedProps.description,
                            container:'body'
                        }).popover('show');
```